# How do I define a custom preprocessor macro in my shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hlsl

I'm trying to use a preprocessor macro in my custom shader so it performs a different step if it's in the Unity Editor:

```
#if defined(IS_UNITY_EDITOR)
    // something
#else
    // other thing
#endif
```

To achieve this, I'm trying [the `Shader.EnableKeyword()` method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Shader.EnableKeyword.html) in a MonoBehavior:

```
if (Application.isEditor) {
    Shader.EnableKeyword("IS_UNITY_EDITOR");
}
```

However, it looks like my shader is being compiled *before* the MonoBehavior can check if it's in the unity editor. I've tried running it on `Start()`, on `Awake()`, `OnEnable()` but the shader never receives the `IS_UNITY_EDITOR` definition. How can I define `IS_UNITY_EDITOR` in my shader before the shader is compiled?

Answer (score 3):

Just stumbled upon [this doc page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-MultipleProgramVariants.html) that explains how multi compile works. In order to be able to create two branches, I have to tell the compiler I'll be using the `IS_UNITY_EDITOR` keyword by writing a `#pragma multi_compile` line:

```glsl
    SubShader {
        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma multi_compile __ IS_UNITY_EDITOR
            #pragma vertex vertShader
            #pragma fragment fragShader
            // ...
```

The double underscore `__` means one version of the shader will have `IS_UNITY_EDITOR` and the other version will have nothing defined.